# Right edge of content covered by vertical scrollbar in centered div

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar, centering

I'd like to create a centered popup with a title and one or more cards under it. Each card contains a small table. When there are more cards than can be displayed, a vertical scrollbar appears. **But there is problem: the vertical scrollbar covers the right edge of the cards.**

The behavior depends on the browser:

- **Chrome**: The problem appears when the page is refreshed, but disappears when the page is resized.
- **Firefox**: The problem is **more serious**, because it doesn't disappear on page resize. There is also a horizontal scrollbar.

The HTML+CSS code that reproduces the problem:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: coral;
}

div#frame {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div#content {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

div.card {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightyellow;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.card:not(.last-card) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightpink;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frame">
    <h1>Frame Title</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card last-card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above snippet viewer does not show the problem in Chrome, so here is a [jsfiddle test page](https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/vyzpq0m5/) which does:

- open the jsfiddle page,
- press F5 to refresh it (the problem appears), then
- resize the results area (the problem disapears).

---

**UPDATE**

In the end I used the original idea of @Rayees-AC: I changed `overflow-y: auto` to `overflow-y: scroll`. His other ideas (hiding the scrollbar entirely or removing `white-space: nowrap`) couldn't be used in my case. I'm grateful for him and @Giant-Realistic-Flying-Tiger for working on this problem!

Comment: the white-space;nowrap is the culprit .. I don't know why but probably a complex calculation involved

Comment: Have you checked [this medium post](https://medium.com/frontend-development-with-js/how-to-hide-scrollbar-and-visible-only-scrolling-79cc3472e503)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#1** - Without showing scrollbarscroll enabled

---

I changed below code.

```
div#content {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
div#content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

I added another div named class `wrapper`

```
.wrapper{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Try this snippet**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: coral;
}

div#frame {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#content {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightblue;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
div#content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;
}

div.card {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightyellow;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.card:not(.last-card) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frame">
    <h1>Frame Title</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card last-card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**#2** - Automatically small content not scrolling

---

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: coral;
}

div#frame {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#content {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}


div.card {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightyellow;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.card:not(.last-card) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frame">
    <h1>Frame Title</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**#3** - Large content makes scrolling

---

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: coral;
}

div#frame {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div#content {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

div.card {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightyellow;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.card:not(.last-card) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frame">
    <h1>Frame Title</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card last-card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kol please check. If any changes inbox me

Comment: This works, but unfortunately the scrollbar will be present even if it's not needed... I will wait for other answers before accepting yours.

Comment: Please check now @kol

Comment: Now worked in both **Firefox** and **Chrome** not  scrollbar present

Comment: Interesting idea... I didn't know the scrollbar can be hidden completely. But this also doesn't solve the problem, because I'd like to show the scrollbar if (and only if) the cards must be scrolled. Thanks for your effort anyway!

Comment: For now, I will go forward with your `overflow-y: scroll` approach, but I plan to offer a bounty, because I have a feeling this problem can be solved somehow using `overflow-y: auto`.

Comment: Now I used ```overflow-y: auto``` but I add another div ```wrapper```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219617/discussion-between-kol-and-rayees-ac).

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding-right` and `overflow:hidden` for only Firefox. This works perfectly.

Also I can't see any problem for Chrome.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

div#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: coral;
}

div#frame {
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div#content {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

div.card {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightyellow;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.card:not(.last-card) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightpink;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* check firefox browser */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  div#content{
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  div.card {
    padding-right:25px; /* 10px card padding + 15px firefox scrollbar width  */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frame">
    <h1>Frame Title</h1>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!---->
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card last-card">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>John Doe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Age</td>
              <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Notes</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting idea. But the problem is the number of cards can be different every time I open the popup, and when the number is so small there is no need for scrolling, your solution still keeps the large right-side padding.