# Divs to fix under one another

Tags: html, css

How can I make head and main tabs fixed one below another? Please note the rows needs to scroll.cannot combine these under another div as they as angular components in separate files

```css
.pages {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div id="head"/>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="tabs" class="pages">
        </div>
    <div id="rows">
</div>
```

Comment: the main div is inside the head div. Further, none of these divs have any content. We need more details to answer this question. I suspect this isn't your actual / full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this,

Add `position:fixed` to **#head, #main, #tabs** with width and height as your needs.

```
#head, #main, #tabs {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  height:20px;
}
```

I added to each top has it's height here i given **20px** to all.

so, **top:0px; top:20px; top:40px;** respectively with background color to identify the div.

```
#head{
  top:0;
  background:green;
}
#main{
  top:20x;
  background:blue;
}
#tabs{
  top:40px;
  background: black;
}
```

Then row is scrollable. here also we given above fixed width then add absolute positioning to row id. that is with **overflow-y:scroll**

```
#rows{
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  color:#111;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

```css
#head, #main, #tabs {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  height:20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-indent:10px;
}
#head{
  top:0;
  background:green;
}
#main{
  top:20x;
  background:blue;
}
#tabs{
  top:40px;
  background: black;
}

#rows{
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top: 60px;
  height: 100vh;
  color:#111;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  background: yellow;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">Head
    <div id="main">Main</div>
    <div id="tabs" class="pages">Tabs</div>
    <div id="rows">
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
      <p>scroll to bottom</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you not showing scrollbar but enabling scrolling by adding below style

```
#rows {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
#rows::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

**[Already  answered in example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358951/right-edge-of-content-covered-by-vertical-scrollbar-in-centered-div/63359200?noredirect=1#answer-63359200)**

Comment: Thanks. It is possible to remove the page scrollbar? Or scroll rows with showing the scrollbar? Actually now I get 2 scrollbars

Comment: ok i updated it by hide scrollbar and enable scrolling :) enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is the scenario you were looking forward to. head and main tags are now placed one below another .

```css
.pages {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
/* code to place head and main tags one below the other without wrapping them */
#head{
background-color: yellow;
top: 0;
}
/* in order to keep main and head fixed but scroll through rows div determine the height main and head are occupying and set top attribute of main to the same as below */
#main{
background-color: orange;
top: 18px;
}
#rows{
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#head,
#main{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">head</div>
<div id="main">
main
  <div id="tabs" class="pages">
  </div>
  <div id="rows">row1</div>
  <div id="rows">row2</div>
  <div id="rows">row3</div>
  <div id="rows">row4</div>
  <div id="rows">row5</div>
  <div id="rows">row6</div>
  <div id="rows">row7</div>
  <div id="rows">row8</div>
  <div id="rows">row9</div>
  <div id="rows">row10</div>
  <div id="rows">row11</div>
  <div id="rows">row12</div>
  <div id="rows">row13</div>
  <div id="rows">row1</div>
  <div id="rows">row2</div>
  <div id="rows">row3</div>
  <div id="rows">row4</div>
  <div id="rows">row5</div>
  <div id="rows">row6</div>
  <div id="rows">row7</div>
  <div id="rows">row8</div>
  <div id="rows">row9</div>
  <div id="rows">row10</div>
  <div id="rows">row11</div>
  <div id="rows">row12</div>
  <div id="rows">row13</div>
  <div id="rows">row1</div>
  <div id="rows">row2</div>
  <div id="rows">row3</div>
  <div id="rows">row4</div>
  <div id="rows">row5</div>
  <div id="rows">row6</div>
  <div id="rows">row7</div>
  <div id="rows">row8</div>
  <div id="rows">row9</div>
  <div id="rows">row10</div>
  <div id="rows">row11</div>
  <div id="rows">row12</div>
  <div id="rows">row13</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is it. But instead of two divs imagine you have another below main called rows. I want main and head to be fixed but rows to scroll. I can't put head and main under one outer div because these are separate components of angular

Comment: i have tried fixing the main and head and kept rows free , please check if this serves your purpose. And yes I do agree with you, this is a platform where people are putting in their best efforts to help each other @user2837961

Comment: But rows not scrolling.

Comment: Yes rows need to scroll. I just realised that.

Answer (score 0):

Just set display: fixed; on #head and #tabs. also adjust hight so that they bellow each other.